# Java - get the quotient and remainder in the same step?

Tags: java, integer-division

It seems that in order to find both the quotient and remainder of a division in Java, one has to do:

```
int a = ...
int b = ...

int quotient = a / b;
int remainder = a % b;
```

Is there a way to write this so that the quotient and remainder are found in a single step (one division operation)? Or does Java already automatically optimize this code so that they are?

Comment: How would you do it in a single operation on paper?

Comment: You can't assign a value to two different variables with two different values in one line.

Comment: @Shark On paper, long division provides you with the quotient and remainder at the same time. I am told division algorithms tend to only provide one or the other.

Comment: not really. long division is something else... consider `11` and `5`. `11` divided by `5` is `2`. remainder of `11/5` is `1`. long division would give you `2.2`, which isn't both things in one operation.

Comment: @Shark you can stop long division at any step. You get that `5` goes into `11` twice. `2*5=10`. `11-10=1=remainder`.

Comment: In Java there is not way to do that exactly. When it gets JIT’d it may simplify it into the single `idiv` instruction. You could also potentially use JNI, but that will likely end up being significantly slower.

Comment: @vandench Thank you! That is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: a%b --> what it provides?? It provides Remainder. But a/b provides quotient.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806366/6735159), Java seems to optimize such code by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural behaviour of all architectures is for the divide instructions to supply the quotient and remainder in separate registers (for binary) or storage areas (for packed decimal as found on the IBM zSeries). The only high level language that I know of that does the same is COBOL. It does always seem wasteful having to repeat the divide instruction again to get the remainder.

Comment: C's stdlib has `div()`, python has `divmod()`, C# has `Math.DivRem()`, so there seems to be support for it in most languages. Java seems to support it only for BigInteger (and related) with `.divideAndRemainder()`, but it's probably only relevant for such special cases.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this in one step as both are different operations. One is division and other is remainder. So you require two variables to store result for both operations.

Comment: But the computer finds the remainder when it does division right? I want to avoid doing a second division just to get the remainder.

Comment: @FuzzyCat444 "the computer finds the remainder when it does division right?" - no, it finds the quotient. Remainders are a separate instruction.

Comment: @Strikegently That answers my question fully then

Comment: @Strikegently I found on one post by Reinderien [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454574/how-do-computers-find-modulus&ved=2ahUKEwipgJCiwczdAhXtRN8KHVZmAzMQFjAMegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1Kuvj1ncwiXZJ4RXO9kHmo) that "Often, the modulus and divide operations on a processor are the same thing. For instance, refer to http://jsimlo.sk/docs/cpu/index.php/div.html. This is the implementation of the divide instruction on Intel processors."

Comment: But Java can't run assembly because different processors have different instruction sets. You could perhaps do this in an inline `__asm` block in C, but not Java, without overcomplicating things... By writing the necessary C code, compiling it as a shared library, loading the library, and invoking the necessary JNI instruction to return a `Pair<Integer, Integer>` which would include the quotient and the remainder.

Comment: @FuzzyCat444 As mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/q/5454574/6407858  this is the case with assembly.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to do this,

```
int a = ...
int b = ...

int quotient = a / b;
int remainder = b - (a * b);
```

uses slightly less CPU, but there's not much in it unless you're doing it lots of times. Doing it a billion times took 5.3 seconds the first way, 3.8 the second. There's a FOR loop in there too in my test.

Comment: int remainder = a - (quotient * b);

Answer (score -3):

```
public int []result (int a , int b){
int quotient = a / b;
int remainder = a % b;
int [] array=new int[2];
array[0]=quotient;
array[1]=remainder;
return array;
}

public void main(){

int a=..;
int b=...;

int [] results=result(a,b);
}
```

Comment: If you pretend that that is "a single step" then it is the perfect solution!

Comment: This is doing the same that the OP wants to avoid. Two operations, rather than one.